# Magento add existing comment to order email

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have installed the [**iwd_onepagecheckout extension**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/iwd-free-one-page-step-checkout-6454.html).

Customers have the possibility to add a comment to their order.

Now I want to add this ‘comment’ to the order email. The comment is to be saved in Table `sales_flat_order_status_history`, which has the columns:

> entity_id, parent_id, is_customer_notified, is_visible_on_front, comment, status, created_at, entity_name

I have searched the forums but cannot find out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above is correct. However it duplicates the comment in the admin panel. You have the comment once without notifying customer, and a second time with notifying customer.

You need to comment or remove the line `$data['order']->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)->setIsVisibleOnFront(true)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);` since that adds the comment to the order page on the admin side, but it doesn't notify the customer.

So the final script should be:

```
public function addHistoryComment($data)
{
    $comment    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getOrderCustomerComment();
    $comment    = trim($comment); 
    if (!empty($comment))
    {
        $order = $data->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
        $order->setCustomerComment($comment);
        $order->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);
        $order->setCustomerNote($comment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

In observer.php from the onepagecheckout extension:

```
public function addHistoryComment($data)
{
$comment    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getOrderCustomerComment();
$comment    = trim($comment); 
    if (!empty($comment))
    {
    $data['order']->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)->setIsVisibleOnFront(true)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order = $data->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
    $order->setCustomerComment($comment);
    $order->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);
    $order->setCustomerNote($comment);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Do I have to put also a var code to my transaction-mail, something like {{var order.comment}} to see the comments in order mail?
Regards snap